# CollectionView content height size doesn't properly update inside tableView cell

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uicollectionview

I have a collectionView inside a tableView cell. I'm using a custom flowLayout to customize collectionView cells (all have to be custom size and aligned to left) and update the collectionView height and fit all elements inside it.

The tableView cell is auto growing. So the collectionView have to adjust to the content, and the tableViewCell have to adjust to collectionView.

Here is my tableView cell class, with collectionView configuration inside:

```
import UIKit

class SearchStationsTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {
    var delegate : SearchStationsTableViewCellProtocol?
    static let heightForRow = 234
    var servicos = [String]()
    var serviceList = ServicesList()
    var station : Station?
    @IBOutlet weak var background: UIView!
    @IBOutlet weak var nameLabel : UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var seeOnMapButton : UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var favoriteButton: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var addressLabel : UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var distanceLabel : UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var collectionView : UICollectionView!

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        self.background.shadowWith(color: UIColor.black.cgColor, opacity: 0.1, size: CGSize(width: 0.0, height: 3.0), radius: 5.0)
        self.collectionView.delegate = self
        self.collectionView.dataSource = self
        registerCells()
    }

    func registerCells() {
        collectionView?.register(UINib(nibName: "StationFiltersCollectionViewCell", bundle: nil), forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "StationFiltersCollectionViewCell")
    }

    /// Configura células da tableView
    ///
    /// - Parameter station:
    func configure(station: Station){
        // constraintCollectionHeight?.constant = 0.0
       let columnLayout = FlowLayout(
            minimumInteritemSpacing: 5,
            minimumLineSpacing: 5,
            sectionInset: UIEdgeInsets(top: 1, left: 1, bottom: 1, right: 1)
        )
        collectionView?.collectionViewLayout = columnLayout
        collectionView.isScrollEnabled = false
        self.station = station
        self.nameLabel.text = station.nomeFantasia
        self.addressLabel.text = station.endereco
        if(station.isFavorite)!{
            self.favoriteButton.setImage(UIImage(named: "icFavoriteMarked"), for: .normal)
            self.favoriteButton.isUserInteractionEnabled = false
        }else{
            self.favoriteButton.setImage(UIImage(named:"icFavorite"), for: .normal)
            self.favoriteButton.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
        }

        if let _servicos = station.servicos, _servicos.count > 0{
            self.servicos = _servicos
            self.collectionView?.reloadData()
            let heightSize = self.collectionView.collectionViewLayout.collectionViewContentSize.height
            self.collectionView?.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant:heightSize).isActive = true
        }
    }

    @IBAction func favoriteButton_action(sender: Any){
        self.delegate?.favoriteButtonPressed(sender:self)
    }

    @IBAction func callButon_action(sender: Any){
        self.delegate?.callButtonPressed(station: station!)
    }

    @IBAction func routeButton_action(sender: Any){
        self.delegate?.routeButtonPressed(station: station!)
    }

    @IBAction func seeOnMap_action(sender: Any){
        self.delegate?.seeOnMapButtonPressed(sender: sender,station: station!)
    }
}

extension SearchStationsTableViewCell : UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDataSource{
    public func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int{
        return servicos.count
    }

    public func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell{
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "StationFiltersCollectionViewCell", for: indexPath) as! StationFiltersCollectionViewCell
        if(ServicesList.haveImage(serviceName: serviceList.serviceName[indexPath.row])){
            cell.filterImage?.image = UIImage(named: serviceList.getImage(serviceName: serviceList.serviceName[indexPath.row]))
            cell.filterName?.text = ""
        }else{
            let title = serviceList.getFriendlyName(serviceName: serviceList.serviceName[indexPath.row])
            cell.filterName?.text = title
            cell.filterImage?.image = UIImage()
        }
        return cell
    }
}

class FlowLayout: UICollectionViewFlowLayout {
    required init(minimumInteritemSpacing: CGFloat = 0, minimumLineSpacing: CGFloat = 0, sectionInset: UIEdgeInsets = .zero) {
        super.init()

        estimatedItemSize = UICollectionViewFlowLayoutAutomaticSize
        self.minimumInteritemSpacing = minimumInteritemSpacing
        self.minimumLineSpacing = minimumLineSpacing
        self.sectionInset = sectionInset
        //sectionInsetReference = .fromSafeArea
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }

    override func layoutAttributesForElements(in rect: CGRect) -> [UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes]? {
        let layoutAttributes = super.layoutAttributesForElements(in: rect)!.map { $0.copy() as! UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes }
        guard scrollDirection == .vertical else { return layoutAttributes 
     }

        // Filter attributes to compute only cell attributes
        let cellAttributes = layoutAttributes.filter({ $0.representedElementCategory == .cell })

        // Group cell attributes by row (cells with same vertical center) and loop on those groups
        for (_, attributes) in Dictionary(grouping: cellAttributes, by: { ($0.center.y / 10).rounded(.up) * 10 }) {
            // Set the initial left inset
            var leftInset = sectionInset.left

            // Loop on cells to adjust each cell's origin and prepare leftInset for the next cell
            for attribute in attributes {
                attribute.frame.origin.x = leftInset
                leftInset = attribute.frame.maxX + minimumInteritemSpacing
            }
        }

        return layoutAttributes
    }
}
```

Comment: as with `tableView` cell is Auto Growing not `tableView` itself. you can give `collectionView Cell` height and width inside `collectionViewLayout` but for CollectionView itself you need to calculate its height by yourself then tableView cell will get Auto Growing height from the CollectionView as you have vertical scrolling.